# How to scan text from a file and save into an array Java

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I am trying to read a string in from a text file, split the string whenever there are spaces, and store each word in an array of strings:

eg. input `"Hello i am a sentence"`

output `[Hello, i, am, a, sentence]`

I currently have the following

```
Scanner sc = null;
      try
      {
        sc = new Scanner(new FileReader(args[0]));
        LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        String str = sc.nextLine();
        for(String i:str.split(" ")){
           list.add(i);
        }
        String[] arguments = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
        System.out.println(arguments);
      }
      catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
      finally
      {
          if (sc != null) sc.close();
      }
```

But i am unable to convert the list into an array and i get the following output

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@45ee12a7
```

Comment: Is this the output you want ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `for` loop to fill the array like this:

```
String[] arguments = list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    arguments[i] = list.get(i);
}
```

And use `foreach` to iterate and print elements of the array:

```
for (String arg: arguments) {
    System.out.println(arg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to make it `List` and again convert into normal `Array`, Just simply do like this, Let's say it's your **String**

```
 String string = "Hello i am a sentence";
```

**You can do either**

```
 String[] array = string.split("\\s", -1);
```

**OR**

```
String[] array = string.split(" ", -1);
```

Both gives same result!